# Ruby on Rails: Adding jQueryUI and Bootstrap icons on production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, asset-pipeline

I have problem with showing icons on production environment. I located files jQueryUI and Bootstrap in /vendor/ directory, then i add config.assets.paths in assets.rb:
`Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist")
 Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("vendor/jquery-ui-1.12.1")`

I also added 'require' statements in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/javascripts/application.js. After that i try:

`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

and restart apache.
Bootstrap and jQueryUI works fine but i can't add icons (or glyphicons from Bootstrap). When i change environment to development icons works fine. The problem is only on production environment. I have tried add png files with icons and fonts files with glyphicons to /vendor/assets/images/ and app/assets/images/ and then change url addresses in css files to assests/images/file_name.png but it doesn't work. Could it be some issue with configuration config/environments/production.rb or something like that? It is strange that everything works fine on development, but production not.

Comment: please format this so that it's readable.

Comment: I have this same problem.  wondering if you were able to fix it somehow?  Can't seem to use the icons, the ui-icons .png files won't load.